# Executing Javascript file from a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am having trouble calling a Javascript file to be executed. Here is the Javascript reference link to the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="snow.js"></script>
```

Now the problem that I am having is that I want to have a certain link activate the script upon clicking a link.

```
<a href="#" onClick=""><img src="myimage.png" /></a>
```

Because the script for the file is actually external, I guess my primary question is how would I go about executing an external script using either Javascript or jQuery? I'm really lost right now, so all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: function addScript(url,d){ d=dcoument; d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode.appendChild(d.createElement('script')).src=url; }

Comment: does snow.js execute immediately upon loading or does it contain a function you need to call?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="snow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="snow.js"><img src="myimage.png" /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

And then, in file snow.js, you put whatever javascript you want to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: put every thing in the javascript function in side a function

```
function myFunction()
{
// all the code in the script file
}
```

step 2 : call this function on click event

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="myimage.png" /></a>
```